# Ошибка при создании двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь решить задачу на создание двумерного динамического массива. Но выдаёт ошибку на строке `arr[h][g] = rand() % 20;` (вторая функция). Подскажите, что не так.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
int **stvor(int h,int g);
void organiz(int h, int g, int **arr);
void del(int h, int g, int **arr);
using namespace std;
int **stvor(int h, int g){
    int **arr = new int *[h];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[g];
    }
    return arr;
}
void organiz(int h, int g, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < g; i++)
    {
        arr[h][g] = rand() % 20;
        cout << setw(6) << arr[h][g];
    }
    return;
}
void del(int h, int g, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        delete[]arr[g];
    }
    delete[]arr;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    srand((signed)time(NULL));
    int **mas; int n, m;
    cout << "input m = "; cin >> m;
    cout << "input n = "; cin >> n; cout << endl;
    mas = stvor(m, n);
    organiz(m, n, mas);
    del(m, n, mas);     

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Harry, Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00184ED9 в динмас_2в.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xFDFDFE09.

Comment: Ошибка/опечатка тут: `for (int j = 0; j < g; i++)`, должно быть `j++`

Answer (score 3):

Эти две функции, `organiz` и `del`, содержат ошибки.

В первой функции вместо предложений

```
    arr[h][g] = rand() % 20;
       ^^^^^^
    cout << setw(6) << arr[h][g];
                          ^^^^^^
```

должно быть

```
    arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
       ^^^^^^
    cout << setw(6) << arr[i][j];
                          ^^^^^^^
```

То есть вы неправильно указываете индексы.

И в этом цикле опечатка

```
void organiz(int h, int g, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < g; j++)
                          ^^^^
```

Вот как может выглядеть эта функция

```
void organiz(int h, int g, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < g; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            cout << setw(6) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Во-второй функции должно быть

```
void del(int h, int g, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        delete[]arr[i];
                   ^^^^
    }

    delete[]arr;
}
```

Второй параметр `g` не используется и может быть удален из объявления функции.

Также в этом предложении в main следует написать

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
       ^^^^^^^^
```

Также это неудачное решение записывать идентификаторы в виде русских слов латинскими буквами. Используйте английские слова. Иначе трудно читать программу.

Comment: спасибо, исправил, но все же не работает

Comment: @K.Mew Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: при запуске выдает сообщение: "Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00FA5F49 в динмас_2в.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xFDFDFDFD."

Comment: @K.Mew У вас в цикле неверный индекс используется. Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка у вас, надо понимать, не при компиляции, а при выполнении? так оно и понятно: вы создали массив `h x g`, и присваиваете значения элементу за рамками массива - `arr[h][g]`...

Может, вы все же имели в виду

```
void organiz(int h, int g, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < g; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            cout << setw(6) << arr[i][j];
        }
    return;
}
```

Еще во вложенном цикле нужно `i++` на `j++` изменить.

Вот [тут](http://ideone.com/Lk3TgA) окончательный работающий код.

Comment: исправил, но все ещё выдаёт ошибку

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.